# Android Hilt - Why can't I Inject a Dependency into MyViewModel without app complaining that my ViewModel doesn't have a zero argument constructor

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

Not sure What I have gotten wrong since I have followed [the Hilt View Model Documentation](https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model) as closely as possible.

I am trying to achieve the most basic of Dependency Injection in Android using Hilt, but somehow it is not working. Whenever I run my App, it will crash on launch, complaining that it cannot find a zero-argument constructor for my ViewModel, even though I'm trying to Inject my dependencies through the ViewModel's constructor, and giving this stack trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myHealthConnect.myweightaverage/com.myHealthConnect.myweightaverage.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.myHealthConnect.myweightaverage.viewmodel.MainActivityViewModel
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4169)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.myHealthConnect.myweightaverage.viewmodel.MainActivityViewModel
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:204)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:324)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:306)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:280)
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:53)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:35)
    at com.myHealthConnect.myweightaverage.activity.MainActivity.getViewModel(MainActivity.kt:21)
    at com.myHealthConnect.myweightaverage.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:29)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8591)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8570)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.myHealthConnect.myweightaverage.viewmodel.MainActivityViewModel.<init> []
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2363)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2201)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:202)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:324) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:306) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:280) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:53) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:35) 
    at com.myHealthConnect.myweightaverage.activity.MainActivity.getViewModel(MainActivity.kt:21) 
    at com.myHealthConnect.myweightaverage.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:29) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8591) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8570) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4150) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

Here are the relevant files:

project level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.45' apply false
}
```

app level build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.45" apply false
}

android {
    namespace 'com.myHealthConnect.myweightaverage'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myHealthConnect.myweightaverage"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.health.connect:connect-client:1.0.0-alpha11'
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.45")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.45")
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}

// Allow references to generated code
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true

    javacOptions {
        option("-Adagger.hilt.android.internal.disableAndroidSuperclassValidation=true")
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Check whether Health Connect is installed or not -->
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.healthdata" />
    </queries>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_WEIGHT"/>

    <application
            android:name=".application.MyApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
            android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyWeightAverage"
            android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
            tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
            tools:targetApi="31">


        <activity
                android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
                android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

                <action android:name="androidx.health.ACTION_SHOW_PERMISSIONS_RATIONALE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                    android:value=""/>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MyApplication.kt :

```
import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication : Application()
```

AppModule.kt :

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.health.connect.client.HealthConnectClient
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.android.components.ViewModelComponent
import dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext
import dagger.hilt.android.scopes.ViewModelScoped
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @ViewModelScoped
    fun provideHealthConnectClient(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context) =
        if (HealthConnectClient.isProviderAvailable(appContext)) {
            HealthConnectClient.getOrCreate(appContext)
        } else {
            throw NullPointerException()
        }
}
```

MainActivity.kt :

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.myHealthConnect.myweightaverage.R
import com.myHealthConnect.myweightaverage.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.myHealthConnect.myweightaverage.viewmodel.MainActivityViewModel
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    }
}
```

MainActivityViewModel.kt :

```
import androidx.health.connect.client.HealthConnectClient
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val healthConnectClient: HealthConnectClient
) : ViewModel() {
    init {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add the dagger-hilt plugin in your **project-level** `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.45' apply false
}
```

Comment: didn't fix anything, but I will add it into my original question so no one makes the same suggestion.

Comment: Can you remove "version "2.45" apply false" after the app-level dagger-hilt gradle plugin declaration? Use "id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")" only.

Comment: This cause Gradle to fail to Sync
`* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)`